# Is it possible to use pyodbc to export data from a Power BI Datamart?

Tags: python, powerbi, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I have read that Power BI Datamarts are, under the hood, an Azure SQL Database. Therefore I thought it might be possible to pull data from a Power BI Datamart using Python's pyodbc package.

I followed Microsoft's quickstart tutorial to connect to Azure SQL db's, but have failed to get very far with it. Given I'm a bit of a novice with Python I wondered whether my failing is to do with an actual limitation, or if it's just my sucky code.

Here's my code:

```
server = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx.datamart.pbidedicated.windows.net'
database = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
username = 'email@xxxxxxxx.com'
password = 'xxxxxxxxxx'   
driver= 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server'

with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 3 name, collation_name FROM sys.databases")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
            row = cursor.fetchone()
```

The error I get is as follows:

> OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.\r\n (10054) (SQLDriverConnect); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10054); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')

I've searched around for an answer but am drawing blanks. Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: it looks like you want to connect using azure ad auth or is just a weird username you chose in the example?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked and there is indeed a limitation on this feature at the moment (it is still in preview). As stated [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Datamart-SQL-Server-Connection-String-Details-Port-number-Share/m-p/2540097), it is only possible to connect with version 18 of SSMS to the datamart as it contains a whitelisted applicationId.

However, even if pyodbc would be a supported type, then your code would never run as azure ad auth is the only supported auth method. see [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/wiki/Connect-to-Azure-SQL-Database), how this would work in theory (works for any other azure sql instance)

Comment: Thanks Tarek, appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1):

ODBC appears to work now.

In the SQL (TDS) endpoint, at least currently, the database name is not the same as the Datamart name.  And you must use an [AAD authentication type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver16).

You can discover the database name like this:

```
import pyodbc

server = '<yourconnectionstring>.datamart.pbidedicated.windows.net'
database = 'master'
driver= 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server'

with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 3 name, collation_name FROM sys.databases")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
            row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Note, I've only tested ODBC connectivity in the Microsoft internal tenant, which is a bit ahead of your tenant in code deployments.

Comment: Thanks David. This looks pretty close to working. My issue now is that I'm getting timeout errors, i.e. "Unable to complete login process due to delay in login response" .. But maybe this is because the Microsoft internal tenant is a bit ahead of my tenant.